# Can't get rounded corners on HTML form submit button?

Tags: html, css

I have a submit button for a form in an HTML doc like so:

```
<form id = "submit" method="get" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Download" id="dlbutton"/>
</form>
```

I tried to get rounded corners on it with CSS using the border-radius property, but they still remain sharp:

```
#dlbutton{
    background:#223445;
    color:#FFFFFF ;
    border: 1px solid #223445;
    border-radius: 18px 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20em;
    height: 5em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

I have another button on another page that is style exactly the same and has rounded corners, except in the html the button is like :

```
<p><button class="clickable" id="clickable">Click me</button></p>
```

I'm using the latest Firefox. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot semicolons (`;`). Change:

```
border-radius: 18px
-moz-border-radius: 5px
```

to:

```
border-radius: 18px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
```

Also, I would recommend adding:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

for better cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: @guts don't say that. We all have to start from somewhere! :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope these links will help you out,please check them:

- http://cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/button-styling.htm
- http://snipplr.com/view/43278/

Example of button:

CSS code:

```
// FIRST STYLE THE BUTTON
input#bigbutton {
width:500px;
background: #3e9cbf; // the colour of the button
padding: 8px 14px 10px; // apply some padding inside the button
border:1px solid #3e9cbf; // required or the default border for the browser will appear
cursor:pointer; // forces the cursor to change to a hand when the button is hovered
// Style the text
font-size:1.5em;
font-family:Oswald, sans-serif; 
letter-spacing:.1em;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); // give the text a shadow 
color: #fff;
/*use box-shadow to give the button some depth - see cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/box-shadow.htm#demo7 for more info on this technique*/
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #3e9cbf, 0px 5px 0px 0px #205c73, 0px 10px 5px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #3e9cbf, 0px 5px 0px 0px #205c73, 0px 10px 5px #999;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #3e9cbf, 0px 5px 0px 0px #205c73, 0px 10px 5px #999;
/*give the corners a small curve*/
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
// SET THE BUTTON'S HOVER AND FOCUS STATES
input#bigbutton:hover, input#bigbutton:focus {
color:#dfe7ea;
/*reduce the size of the shadow to give a pushed effect*/
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #3e9cbf, 0px 2px 0px 0px #205c73, 0px 2px 5px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #3e9cbf, 0px 2px 0px 0px #205c73, 0px 2px 5px #999;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #3e9cbf, 0px 2px 0px 0px #205c73, 0px 2px 5px #999;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input id="bigbutton" type="submit" value="Big Button That Needs Clicking" />
```

Comment: This answer could be reduced by like 90%, to be honest. Try keeping it shorter and more consist.

Comment: I know, I just came up with an example how it could look like.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that all three of these do the same thing but on different browsers so you can set them to the same parameter:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
```

So you can them to your code as follows:

```
#dlbutton {
  background:#223445;
  color:#FFFFFF ;
  border: 1px solid #223445;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
          border-radius: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 20em;
  height: 5em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```